# Get first nth values from singly linked list

Tags: linked-list

If we insert nodes at the end then it is simple, but what if I insert nodes at the beginning ? One solution which came into my mind was to make it the same way as when inserting at the end and then just reverse the list , but I am interested into nicer solution. Thanks

Comment: Please add the programming language.

Answer (score 0):

In your question, items (nodes) will be it the reverse order that they were inserted.  For "easy" forward and reverse traversals you really need a double linked list (next and prev pointers).  To do what you ask with a single linked list, there are several possibilities.  You could traverse the list keeping only up to n items in a stack and then print the stack, but of course then you also need a stack data structure.  If the last is not too big your could use recursion.  If it is too big you will get a Stack Overflow :).  Here is an example in C:

```
struct Node
{
   int value; // Assume int values in list
   Node *next;
};

typedef struct
{
  struct Node* first;
} List;

// This is a recursive function which will first work its way to the end 
// of the list and print n elements on the way back out.  You can replace
// printing with any processing you want.
int print_first_n(struct Node *p, int n)
{
   if (p == NULL) return n;
   if (p->next != NULL) n = first_n(p->next, n);

   if (n > 0) 
   {
     printf("%d\n", p->value);
     n -= 1;
   }

   return n;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   List list = {NULL};
   // (populate list - insert at beginning of list)

   // Print first 10 elements inserted
   print_first_n(list.first, 10);

   return 0;
}
```